# Which suspend/resume pointer is the right one to use?

Tags: linux-kernel, power-management

I am working on power management on an i2c driver and noticed something odd.

`include/linux/i2c.h`

```
struct i2c_driver {
    //...
    int (*suspend)(struct i2c_client *, pm_message_t mesg);
    int (*resume)(struct i2c_client *);
    //...
    struct device_driver driver;
    //...
}
```

`include/linux/device.h`

```
struct device_driver {
    //...
    int (*suspend) (struct device *dev, pm_message_t state);
    int (*resume) (struct device *dev);
    //...
    const struct dev_pm_ops *pm;
    //...
}
```

`include/linux/pm.h`

```
struct dev_pm_ops {
    //...
    int (*suspend)(struct device *dev);
    int (*resume)(struct device *dev);
    //...
}
```

Why are there so many suspend and resume function pointers?  Some kind of legacy thing?  Which one should I use for my driver?

I am on an old kernel (2.6.35)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why are there so many suspend and resume function pointers?

1. `i2c_driver` - legacy support.
2. `device_driver` - standard support.
3. `dev_pm_ops` - extended power management.

Notice that they are all *function pointers*.  There is sequencing for the *suspend* and *resume*.  For instance, the **i2c** controller must be *suspended* after the devices but *resumed* before.

> Some kind of legacy thing?

The [`struct i2c_driver`](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/drivers/i2c/i2c-core.c?id=refs/tags/v3.12-rc5#n302) is a legacy mechism.  It existed before the entire power infrastructure was created.  As well, some configurations may exclude the full `struct dev_pm_ops` pointer, but have the `suspend` and `resume` driver hooks.  The full `struct dev_pm_ops` supports *suspend to disk* and other features.  *Suspend to memory* is more common and is given pointers space in `struct device_driver`.  If `struct dev_pm_ops` is non-NULL, the two pointer will be the same. These two should call the same routine in your driver.

> Which one should I use for my driver?

You probably shouldn't use any of them.  It is probably more likely that your driver is part of some other sub-system. <sup>see **Note**</sup>  For instance, the *i2c* is used in *codecs* like the [wm8940.c](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/sound/soc/codecs/wm8940.c?id=refs/tags/v3.12-rc5#n674).  Generally, *i2c* is not the central controlling sub-system.  It is a driver that is used by something else to control a chip-set.  The *sound* sub-system will be suspended before *i2c* and it is better to put your hooks there.  If your driver is pure *i2c*, then use the macros in [pm.h](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/include/linux/pm.h), like `SET_SYSTEM_SLEEP_PM_OPS` to conditionalize the setting of `dev_pm_ops`; so set both of them.  Most likely the `device_driver` will be copied to `dev_pm_ops` if it exists, but doing it explicitly is better.

The [driver-model](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/driver-model/), [i2c power management](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/i2c/writing-clients?id=refs/tags/v3.12-rc5#n277) and [power driver](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/power/devices.txt) documentation have more information on the structure and overviews.

**Note:** In this case, there are multiple `device_driver` structures.  Usually the `i2c_driver` is managed by a controlling driver.  The controlling driver should implement a `suspend`/`resume` for it's sub-system, which uses the `i2c_driver` interface.

Comment: [Which driver is linux going to use](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14972584/how-can-the-linux-kernel-determine-which-driver-a-device-is-going-to-use) is a closed question which might be useful to understand the **note** part.